# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript... or one of its dependencies... what gives?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, assemblies

What does this mean? This only happens on my local IIS where the site used to run fine no problem, it works fine on our DEV/QA servers but on my local machine I'm getting this, what gives? I had no knowledge of us using Microsoft.JScript ever, and doing a search of the project turns up nothing...

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +62
   System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +42
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +65
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid() +13
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection ps) +3182
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash() +73
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate2(StandardDiskBuildResultCache diskCache) +684
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(StandardDiskBuildResultCache diskCache) +50
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize() +320
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() +11203871
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags) +498

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11301302
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4338644
```

UPDATE: This also happens when I try to browse ANYTHING through my local IIS, not just my web app! Though my web app isn't even using this thing at all... I can't even load up the ASP.NET configuration settings thing in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No posted solution worked and I needed to get it back up and running the next business day. Restored to factory default and re-installed everything, it only took about 4 hours of babysitting some restore software + putting VS, svn, filezilla, notepad++, sql manager back on.

Everything is working really great now :P

Answer (score 0):

have you tried cleaning your solution?

Build -> Clean Solution

if that doesn't help closing visual studios, deleting everything in your bin folder ,then re-opening the solution, then do a re-build solution.

Comment: no such luck, also there are only 3 files that are generated in my bin folder the rest I cannot delete (third party DLLs)

Answer (score 0):

It could have relation to [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/470989/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-jscript-version-8-0-0-0-culture-neutral-publickeytoken-b03f5f7f11d50a3a-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly-manife) which seems to be fixed by installing the SP2 for Windows Vista (if this is your case of course).

Another possible reason I can think of, although less probable, is that you are running a 64 bit OS and the assembly has been compiled for 32 bit. In this case you might try setting the application pool in IIS to enable 32 bit support:

[image]

To rule out this possibility you could check the processor architecture `Microsoft.JScript` assembly has been compiled against: MSIL, x86, x64

Comment: Where do I set this? Is this in IIS? If not just keep in mind that this error is not specific to one application, it is thrown by everything I try to access through IIS via web browser, even Microsoft built in configuration pages, or any web app that I try. Also note that this happened suddenly, it was working fine a week ago. (Win7,64)

Comment: Yes, this is in the properties of the application pool in IIS.

Comment: No such luck, looks like it's not related to that. I think tonight I am just going to re-install Windows.

Comment: @Ryan, before taking such drastic measures try reinstalling Visual Studio and the .NET framework (not that this is not drastic but compared to reinstalling Windows :-)).

Comment: I tried that all ready too, it's not that drastic actually. Last night I copied all my files to an external drive, and restored factory default. Re-installed everything quickly, only copied back the data that I really needed. It's only a 4-5 hour deal depending on how much data you have to copy. I love doing it because it makes the system so much snappier.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to enable the assembly bind failure logging as describes in the error message.  This should give you more information about what and why it is failing.
If this doesn't work for youthen you can try using proces monitor from msft. Procmon will tell you all of the files that your webserver is trying to load.

Comment: Tried that too, nothing conclusive. That's what originally led me to suspect disk problems and run check disk but it was fine.