# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript,

Tags: asp.net

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569401/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-jscript-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: Unclear of what you're asking.  Flagging to close.